# dojo mobile, dynamic edge to edge list, css not updating? parser needs to run

Tags: javascript, css, mobile, dynamic, dojo

I am making a dynamic edge to edge list in dojo mobile. I am dynamically adding li to my main ul. Dojo mobile takes care of the initial set of li tags making them styled correctly and applying all the classes that dojo mobile needs. However, when javascript removes the old li and makes new ones, it dojo mobile doesn't recognize the new tags and style them. Is there a way to make dojo mobile go back through and add in it's styling? I think that I just need to figure out how to re-run the parser.
Here is what I have so far and what it looks like:

```
    function changeToCategoryNav()
{
    $("#browseLabel").hide();
    $("#CategoryLabel").show();
    $("#navList").html("");
    $("#navList").append(
    "<li data-dojo-type='dojox.mobile.ListItem' data-dojo-props='moveTo:" + '"general"' + "'> Boxes & Covers </li>" + 
    "<li data-dojo-type='dojox.mobile.ListItem' data-dojo-props='moveTo:" + '"wifi"' + "' onclick='changeToSectionNav();'> EMT </li>" + 
    "<li data-dojo-type='dojox.mobile.ListItem' data-dojo-props='moveTo:" + '"general"' + "'> Enclosures & Wireway </li>" + 
    "<li data-dojo-type='dojox.mobile.ListItem' data-dojo-props='moveTo:" + '"wifi"' + "'> Fittings </li>" + 
    "<li data-dojo-type='dojox.mobile.ListItem' data-dojo-props='moveTo:" + '"general"' + "'> Liquidite </li>" + 
    "<li data-dojo-type='dojox.mobile.ListItem' data-dojo-props='moveTo:" + '"wifi"' + "'> PVC </li>"
    );
}

function changeToSectionNav()
{
    $("#SectionLabel").show();
    $("#navList").html("");
    $("#navList").append(
    "<li data-dojo-type='dojox.mobile.ListItem' data-dojo-props='moveTo:" + '"general"' + "'> Diecast </li>" + 
    "<li data-dojo-type='dojox.mobile.ListItem' data-dojo-props='moveTo:" + '"wifi"' + "'> Elbows </li>" + 
    "<li data-dojo-type='dojox.mobile.ListItem' data-dojo-props='moveTo:" + '"general"' + "'> Steel Compression </li>" + 
    "<li data-dojo-type='dojox.mobile.ListItem' data-dojo-props='moveTo:" + '"wifi"' + "'> Steel Compression Insulated </li>" + 
    "<li data-dojo-type='dojox.mobile.ListItem' data-dojo-props='moveTo:" + '"general"' + "'> Steel Compression Raintight </li>" + 
    "<li data-dojo-type='dojox.mobile.ListItem' data-dojo-props='moveTo:" + '"wifi"' + "'> Steel Set Screw </li>"
    );
}




<ul id="navList" data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.EdgeToEdgeList" data-dojo-props='transition:"flip"'>
                    <li data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.ListItem"
                        data-dojo-props='moveTo:"general"'>
                        Conduit & Raceway
                    </li>
                    <li data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.ListItem"
                        data-dojo-props='moveTo:"wifi"'>
                        Control & Automation
                    </li>
                    <li data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.ListItem"
                        data-dojo-props='moveTo:"general"'>
                        Datacom
                    </li>
                    <li data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.ListItem"
                        data-dojo-props='moveTo:"wifi"'>
                        Distribution Equipment
                    </li>
                    <li data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.ListItem"
                        data-dojo-props='moveTo:"general"' onclick="changeToCategoryNav();">
                        Fittings & Boxes
                    </li>
                    <li data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.ListItem"
                        data-dojo-props='moveTo:"wifi"'>
                        Fuses
                    </li>
                </ul>
```

[image: The first list - how I want it to look]
[image: After clicking an option, the new list populated - not styled correctly]